# Is it possible to change the border of a single Entry in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I was wondering if someone can point out how I can change a single entry?. I've made a custom renderer which changes the border of an entry to red but what I really want is only to change one entry if validation fails from black to red.

Picture of entries:

### [image]

My renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(App.RedFrameEntry), typeof(RedFrameEntryRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class RedFrameEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {

        public bool isInvalid = false;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#c60303").ToCGColor();
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
                if (isInvalid)
                {
                    Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my code:

```
private void ChangeEntryOnValidationFail(string text, Entry entry, int numberOfChar)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text.Length < numberOfChar)
    {
        // TODO: Change to RedFrameEntry
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Change back to default
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. You should always post code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you create a `CustomEntry` class which has a base class of `Entry`, so instead of changing the border of all entries, you can just call the `CustomEntry` whenever you need it.

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry{
}
```

then use:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(RedFrameEntryRenderer))]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The problem that I'm having is that I'm not sure how to call the CustomEntry in my xaml.cs where I'm doing my validations.

Comment: Check the namespace of your `CustomEntry` class then use it to call the namespace on your XAML. ex. `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TheNamespace;assembly=TheAssembly(notreallyneeded)"` then call it like this `<custom:CustomEntry/>`

Comment: Is there any way to change an existing Entry (Normal one) to CustomEntry in xaml.cs?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Have you tried doing this? `yourEntry = new CustomEntry(){ ...properties...};`

Comment: Yea but it didn't work for me. I think I'm going to implement this the ugly  way (Hide and show entries) untill I find a better solution.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped! You can set this as the accepted answer, so other people would know that this worked